# Displaying Bibliography Photo in IEEE Journal

Tags: graphics, ieeetran

I've formatted my photo as a PDF but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Here is the relevant code (I am using the IEEE bare journal template and `IEEEtran` class with the `journal` option).

Here is the code from the document with dots to indicate filler:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

...

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\fi

...

\begin{document}

...

% biography section
% 
% If you have an EPS/PDF photo (graphicx package needed) extra braces are
% needed around the contents of the optional argument to biography to prevent
% the LaTeX parser from getting confused when it sees the complicated
% \includegraphics command within an optional argument. (You could create
% your own custom macro containing the \includegraphics command to make things
% simpler here.)
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mshell}}]{Michael Shell}
% or if you just want to reserve a space for a photo:

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Michael Shell}
Biography text here.
\end{IEEEbiography}

...

\end{document}
```

I've uncommented the macro line to use it, but it doesn't seem to work for me (yes I have an mshell pdf image in the correct path as a test). This is the offending line (commenting it makes the error go away):

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mshell}}]{Michael Shell}
```

I am getting this error:

```
<mshell.pdf, id=1, 72.27pt x 90.3375pt> <use mshell.pdf> <use mshell.pdf>
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\par ->\hfil \penalty -\@M 
                           \indent 
l.685 \begin{IEEEbiography}{Michael Shell}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Heuristic_Paper.log.
```

The PDF image is only 77KB - I know I've used much larger images in TeX files before with no memory problems.

Comment: This works OK for me: `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}]{Michael Shell}
Biography text here.
\end{IEEEbiography}

\end{document}` Do you have any problems with this example?

Comment: @Gonzalo, I get the same error. @Dan, your example has a missing `\end{IEEEbiography}`.

Comment: Doh! @Aditya that was the problem. I thought it was a macro not an actual declaration. Whoops! Thanks! Make than an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Aditya well, using Dan's code of course there's an error: the line `\begin{IEEEbiography}{Michael Shell}` is superfluous. In the code I proposed that line was removed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two `\begin{IEEEbiography}` lines:

```
\begin{IEEEbiography[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mshell}}]{Michael Shell}

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Michael Shell}
```

The `IEEEbiography` environment cannot be nested. Remove the second line, and everything compiles corrected.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEbiography}
    [{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mshell}}]{Michael Shell}
Biography text here.
\end{IEEEbiography}

...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no problem with the code, just write down the file extension with the file name.

The following code should work.

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mshell.pdf}}]{Michael Shell}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is either necessary of sufficient to provide the filename extension in order to solve the problem? The `\includegraphics` instruction is smart enough to cycle through various plausible filename extensions automatically. If the file `mshell.pdf` exists, it will be found if one specifies `\includegraphics[...]{mshell}`.